# Issue installing python 3.8 using pyenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyenv

I tried installing python using the command pyenv install 3.8.11

Please let me know if you need more info. Thank you for looking.
output:

> BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using python-build 20180424)

```
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20210821132713.23441
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20210821132713.23441.log

Last 10 log lines:
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821132713.23441/Python-3.8.11/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 206, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821132713.23441/Python-3.8.11/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 125, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821132713.23441/Python-3.8.11/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 34, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", code], check=True).returncode
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821132713.23441/Python-3.8.11/Lib/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/python-build.20210821132713.23441/Python-3.8.11/python', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/tmp/tmp7l0fqi9l/setuptools-56.0.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'/tmp/tmp7l0fqi9l/pip-21.1.1-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/tmp/tmp7l0fqi9l\', \'--root\', \'/\', \'--upgrade\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
make: *** [Makefile:1198: install] Error 1
```

log:

> 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/runpy.py", line 203, in run_module
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 241, in load_module
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 709, in _get_module_code
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 570, in _get_data
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 206, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 125, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 34, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", code], check=True).returncode
  File "/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/Lib/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/python-build.20210821140419.301/Python-3.8.11/python', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/tmp/tmp1imhbulh/setuptools-56.0.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'/tmp/tmp1imhbulh/pip-21.1.1-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/tmp/tmp1imhbulh\', \'--root\', \'/\', \'--upgrade\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
make: *** [Makefile:1198: install] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you follow all of the [installation instructions](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) properly?

Comment: I've got a kind of PTSD, when I see that error. Take a look into the log file.

Comment: I believe I did follow them correctly. I'm still new to this, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to look for.

Comment: The error should be in the log file (look at the file where it says `Results logged to /tmp/python-build.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.log`). The error should be towards the bottom of the file. You can include the contents of that file here so someone can help.

Comment: Okay, I think this is the section from that file that you're mentioning. It's a giant file.

Comment: "zlib not available"—do you have `zlib` installed? What operating system are you on?

Comment: I did not install zlib. I was following a tutorial, but I don't see or might have missed that section.  I'm operating on windows 10. I'm not at my pc currently to research what zlib is or does.

Comment: IIRC, pyenv is a bash script. How are you running it on Windows? Via WSL and a Linux distribution? Git Bash? Something else?

Comment: I am using ubuntu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pyenv` requires some packages to build Python from source.

For Ubuntu, from [pyenv wiki: suggested build environment](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment)

```sh
sudo apt-get install make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. I went back and followed the guide, but they left this part out in the video. It was actually included in the written tutorial. Thank you and also thanks to everyone else who participated.

Comment: @Aeton No problem. Could you accept my answer, to flag the question as resolved?

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem but... it is sad that there is no eloquent error message to tell us what is wrong. "returned non-zero exit status 1." is not very eloquent.